# Conditional Field in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have the following SQL Query in MS Access

```
SELECT 
   Laufzettel.ANTRAGSNUMMER, 
   Laufzettel.Versicherungsnummer, 
   DP.DUNKEL,   
   Laufzettel.AEingangDatenstromZWorkflow,
   Laufzettel.BEingangesigniertDokumentZWorkflow,
   Laufzettel.CAusgangDatenstromZWorkflow,
   Laufzettel.DAnlageSchwebeVSL, 
   Laufzettel.EPolicierungVSL
FROM 
   DP, Laufzettel;
```

The DP.DUNKEL is just a single value 1. I want the DP.DUNKEL to be displayed only when Laufzettel.EPolicierungVSL is not NULL else display 0. How can I achieve this as I can't find IF ELSE condition in SQL?

Comment: IF/ELSE is unsupported in Access queries, but `IIF()` does the same thing.  [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS Access you can use the inline IIF(condition,true,false)

in your case.

```
  SELECT 
        Laufzettel.ANTRAGSNUMMER,
       Laufzettel.Versicherungsnummer,
      IIF(ISNULL(Laufzettel.EPolicierungVSL),1,0) AS dunkel
      , Laufzettel.AEingangDatenstromZWorkflow
      , Laufzettel.BEingangesigniertDokumentZWorkflow
      , Laufzettel.CAusgangDatenstromZWorkflow
      , Laufzettel.DAnlageSchwebeVSL
      , Laufzettel.EPolicierungVSL
  FROM Laufzettel;
```

**Note**: since your dunkle column can be calculated, you don't need the DP table. (or at least I don't see any need for it in your SQL)

Answer (score 0):

could be using swithc

```
  SELECT 
        Laufzettel.ANTRAGSNUMMER
      , Laufzettel.Versicherungsnummer
        Switch(
          Not IsNull (Laufzettel.EPolicierungVSL),  DP.DUNKEL
          IsNull (Laufzettel.EPolicierungVSL),  0 
          ) AS dunkel
      , Laufzettel.AEingangDatenstromZWorkflow
      , Laufzettel.BEingangesigniertDokumentZWorkflow
      , Laufzettel.CAusgangDatenstromZWorkflow
      , Laufzettel.DAnlageSchwebeVSL
      , Laufzettel.EPolicierungVSL
  FROM DP, Laufzettel;
```